# PostSharp: Solution-Wide Module Initializer Introduction?

Tags: postsharp

I'm trying to apply a module initializer to all assemblies built in a solution but am not seeing a good way to do this, wondering if there's something I'm missing or maybe a way I can work around this in some way?

For starters, I'm thinking to use a Multicast IAspectProvider configured in a pssln to apply the same global aspect introduction to all assemblies built (there are other scenarios I'm trying to cover in a solution-wide way that I believe this will be helpful for). Regardless of the module initializer scenario, does this seem like an applicable way to programatically apply aspects on a solution-wide basis?

As for the specific scenario of programatic introduction of a module initializer, sadly, it seems like there's no way to introduce types or static members. Is this correct? If so I don't know how I would be able to introduce a module initializer that doesn't already exist in the assembly, but maybe there's some other clever approach I can take?

Comment: I may have a work around for a specific use case in our particular architecture, but I am still interested in this broader approach which may be useful for other scenarios we have

Comment: It is correct that there is no way to introduce static members nor types using PostSharp at the moment. You can suggest to add this feature at https://postsharp.uservoice.com/forums/4949-feature-requests. Could you tell us what exactly you want to achieve? Maybe there's another solution than introducing module initializers.

Comment: Apart from the scenario in my other question you've replied to, I'd like to ensure specific referenced assemblies are initialized when the process first starts, so I'd like all executable apps to use the same initialization routine that will guarantee a specific assembly has been loaded before any normal process running code has executed (for profiling purposes). Since the module initializer will run the same in desktop, web, and service apps I wouldn't have to pointcut at very different types of entry points (App_Start, Main, OnStart, etc.) or apply the aspect to projects individually